# How to search YouTube with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, youtube, htmlunit

I wonder if YouTube could be searched with [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). I started to write code, here it is:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

public class HtmlUnitExampleTestBase {
    private static final String YOUTUBE = "http://www.youtube.com";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        //This is equivalent to typing youtube.com to the adress bar of browser
        HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.youtube.com");

        //Get form where submit button is located
        HtmlForm searchForm = (HtmlForm) currentPage.getElementById("masthead-search");
        //Printing result form
        System.out.println(searchForm.asText());
        final List<HtmlAnchor> listLinks = (List<HtmlAnchor>) newPage.getByXPath("//a[@class='ux-thumb-wrap result-item-thumb']");
        for (int i=0; i<listLinks.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(YOUTUBE + listLinks.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
        }
    }   
}
```

Now I don't know how to type some text into a search field and press Search button.

I saw tutorials about HtmlUnit but I'm having a problem because they use a method named: `getElementByName` but the search button on YouTube doesn't have a name, just an id. Could someone help me?

EDIT: I edited code above code and now I am getting youtube links from first page. But before that I need to sort by upload date and then to grab links. Can someone help me to do sorting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) expert, but there is a workaround. You can add your own button to the form and use it to submit the form.

Here's a code sample with comments:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButton;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class HtmlUnitExampleTestBase {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
      WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
      webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

      // This is equivalent to typing youtube.com to the adress bar of browser
      HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.youtube.com");

      // Get form where submit button is located
      HtmlForm searchForm = (HtmlForm) currentPage.getElementById("masthead-search");

      // Get the input field.
      HtmlTextInput searchInput = (HtmlTextInput) currentPage.getElementById("masthead-search-term");
      // Insert the search term.
      searchInput.setText("Nyan Cat");

      // Workaround: create a 'fake' button and add it to the form.
      HtmlButton submitButton = (HtmlButton) currentPage.createElement("button");
      submitButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
      searchForm.appendChild(submitButton);

      // Workaround: use the reference to the button to submit the form. 
      HtmlPage newPage = submitButton.click();

      System.out.println(newPage.asText());
   }
}
```

Comment: It works. Now I just want to sort results with some criteria other than default. Default is sort by relevance, how to change to sort by upload date?

Comment: @Иван Бишевац: Perhaps it would be better to open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUnit is OK, but I vastly prefer [Watir](http://watir.com/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for web automation.

One of HtmlUnit's weaknesses is its lack of selector methods for getting at DOM elements in a jQuery-like way. Check out the css-selector project, which will add on to HtmlUnit to help you do what you need very easily. There's an intro at [Gooder Code](http://www.goodercode.com/wp/use-css-selectors-with-htmlunit/).

Once you get that working, the selector for the YouTube search form would be ".search-term" and the submit button's selector would be ".search-button"

Comment: Do you recommend me to take Watir or Selemium? I heard here on forum that many people recommends Selenuim.

Comment: @Иван Бишевац: Here's a [comparison of Watir vs Selenium vs Sahi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi/643124#643124).

Comment: @Иван Бишевац: I like them both. If I want really quick-and-easy record/playback and simple functional tests I want to watch, I use Selenium; if I want more powerful control structures, logic, and/or automation, I use Watir.